# Multibib & indentation

Tags: bibliographies, indentation, subdividing, multibib

I use multibib to apply more than one bibliography in my document. The problem is when using more than 9 entrys, there occurs an indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{lit}{Literature1}
%\newcites{lit2}{Literature2}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
  \section*{\refname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Lit1.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{A02,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{A03,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{A04,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{A05,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{A06,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{A07,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{A08,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{A09,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{A10,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{A11,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[A\,#1]}\makeatother
\nocitelit{*}
\bibliographystylelit{plain}
\bibliographylit{Lit1}

\end{document}
```

How can I avoid this indentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indentation has nothing to do with `multibib` but stems from the fact that you enlarging the biblabels with "A ". BibTeX calculates somewhat correctly that the largest label is "10" (see the `bbl` file), where you want the largest label to be "A 10". The simplest option to circumvent this is to use

```
\setbiblabelwidth{1000}
```

from the `multibib` pakage. The other, more involved option is to hack the bibliography style to output the actually desired labels to the `bbl` file.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `multibib`, with the `resetlabels` option, always passes `0` for computing the label width, which is an error, in my opinion.

You can solve the issue with another patch:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
  \section*{\refname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
}{}{}{}
\begingroup\catcode`#=12
\AtBeginDocument{
  \patchcmd\thebibliography
    {\advance\@tempcnta#1}
    {\advance\@tempcnta#1\else\@tempcnta#1}
    {}{}
}
\endgroup
\makeatother
```

The `\AtBeginDocument` and the `\catcode` trick are necessary because `multibib` redefines `\thebibliography` at begin document.

[image]